# Placing a predefined value in the empty fields of an SQL query result

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I need to manipulate the data that a certain SQL query outputs as a result, only by modifying the original query. Since it is s Select-Where-From query, as a novice in SQL I assume I can simply nest it inside another query of this type, resulting in a structure similar to: Select-Where-(Select-Where-From).

The data manipulation simply requires the replacement of all empty fields in a certain column (that was taken from the result of the original query) with a specific predefined value. Here are the two attempts I've made - based on findings from this website - which failed:

```
select NAME_OF_COLUMN, COALESCE(NULLIF(NAME_OF_COLUMN,''), 'Value_to_insert')

from

(THIS IS WHERE THE ORIGINAL SELECT QUERY GOES)
```

This one doesn't throw an error, but nonetheless produces empty fields instead of populating them with the value above, as if only the original query was run.

The 2nd:

```
Select *, NAME_OF_COLUMN=
CASE WHEN NAME_OF_COLUMN IS NULL THEN 'Value_to_insert'
WHEN NAME_OF_COLUMN='' THEN 'Value_to_insert'
ELSE NAME_OF_COLUMN
END

from

(THIS IS WHERE THE ORIGINAL SELECT QUERY GOES)
```

This one throws the following error (forgive me for the messy presentation, but it was not up to me):

```
    java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
, org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Invalid bound column name: CREATOR_USER_NAME., org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Cannot get the result set metadata.
    org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL statement does not return a ResultSet object.
SQL error #1:ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected;
```

Can you please assist me and tell me what am I doing wrong? Perhaps I need to select a specific column and/or use the 'as' command?

Edit: I have attempted replacing the original select which was:

```
select table.column as NAME_OF_COLUMN
```

with this:

```
select nvl(table.column, 'Value_to_insert') as NAME_OF_COLUMN
```

Unfortunately, just like the first attempt, the output is identical to the output of the original query..

Comment: What does "failed" mean? Threw an error? If so, what was the error? Produced an unexpected result? If so, what was the result? Sample data, expected results, and a more detailed explanation of the problem would all be helpful. Potentially, a tag for the actual database product you're using may be appropriate.

Comment: I have elaborated more, as requested.

Answer (score 1):

`NAME_OF_COLUMN=CASE ... END` is invalid in Oracle. You can't assign a column value in (standard) SQL like that.

If you are trying to come up with a column alias: that needs to go *after* the expression:

```
CASE 
  WHEN name_of_column IS NULL THEN 'Value_to_insert'
  WHEN name_of_column = '' THEN 'Value_to_insert'
  ELSE name_of_column
END as name_of_column
```

In Oracle an empty String `''` is converted to `NULL` when you store  the value. So the second condition of your CASE expression will never be true. The whole thing can be simplified to:

```
coalesce(name_of_column, 'Value_to_insert') as name_of_column
```

Note that you need to get rid of the `select *` part and explicitly list all other columns excluding `name_of_column` there, otherwise your query ends up with two columns with the same name.

Comment: It seems that since there is only one column in the original query result, it should look like this:

`select coalesce(name_of_column, 'Value_to_insert') as name_of_column

from

(THIS IS WHERE THE ORIGINAL SELECT QUERY GOES)`

or like this:

`select CASE 
  WHEN name_of_column IS NULL THEN 'Value_to_insert'
  WHEN name_of_column = '' THEN 'Value_to_insert'
  ELSE name_of_column
END as name_of_column

from

(THIS IS WHERE THE ORIGINAL SELECT QUERY GOES)`

Correct?

Comment: As an explanatory note, the syntax `AliasName = <Column or Expression>` _is_ valid in SQL Server's TSQL dialect, so you'll see it used in sample code online. Hence the confusion when trying to implement it on another platform.